# How to add varargs to a structure in c

Tags: c, structure, variadic-functions

I have a c function which accepts variable arguments.**I want to store all the arguments of this function(along with the vararg) in a structure** and pass that structure to another function which will parse all the elements in the structure.
But I dont know how to add the variable argument obtained to the structure.

```
void fun1(char* c,int i,...)
{
  //I want to create a structure
  //of all the input params.
  //But how to add the varargs?
  //Which type am I suppose to declare in structure?

}
```

Could somebody tell me how to do this.Any help or idea will be really helpful!!

Comment: Are all the varargs of the same type? Because if so, then I'd suggest an array.

Comment: There is no way. A structure is something defined at compile-time.

Comment: Did you look at the [`va_list` structure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) and considered it's use?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix The arguments will be different.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to save them to a structure?

Comment: @Myst Will I be able to add this va_list to a structure?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Bcoz I want to make use of all the input arguments in another thread.

Comment: I am courious about the "other function". How can a structure be "parsed" dynamically after compilation?

Comment: You could probably have a member of type `va_list` in your structure.   Although you would not be storing the variable arguments in your structure, you would, in effect, be storing a pointer to them -- which the eventual reader could then access with `va_arg(). You could probably make this work. I'm not sure it would be a good idea, though.

Comment: @adi , you shouldn’t assume anything about the `va_list` implementation, since the standard allows for a wide variety of approaches and defines it as a macro (so it’s better not to add it to another structure). Also, the variable data is stored on the heap, so you shouldn’t assume `malloc` would work with it. But you can use it as a function argument and you can save the parsed data to a structure (assuming it fits).

Comment: @Myst But my vararg will be too long and I want my vararg to be parsed in a separate thread.This is the reason I want to add it in a structure.

Comment: Is der a way I can parse my vararg in a separate thread?

Comment: @SteveSummit Probably not a good idea because the thread that called `va_start` would have to block until the other thread had finished with the `va_list` before it calls `va_end`.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse" the variable arguments?  If you want to store them explicitly in the structure, the first function is going to have to figure out how many of them there are, and of what types, so that it can store them.  Presumably that's not a lot of work.  Then, once they're safely copied into the structure, the other thread can do the real processing work on them (whatever that is).

Comment: @SteveSummit By parsing , I meant figuring out what my varargs actually are! and the length of my varargs are too long and I dont want to parse it in the same calling thread and instead notify another thread to parse it.

Comment: @adi In that case, I believe your task is impossible.  If the actual list contains ten arguments, you are going to have to store ten things in your structure.  If that's too long, there's nothing you can do.  As mentioned in one of my other comments, you could store a reference to the argument list, that is, store the `va_list`, but as Ian Abbott correctly pointed out, you'd have to have the calling thread block until the worker thread had finished, otherwise the pointed-to arguments would disappear.

Comment: The original thread would certainly need to block until the worker thread has finished with the `va_list`. I'm not sure what happens if the worker thread uses `va_copy` to copy the original `va_list`, then unblocks the original thread (which can now call `va_end` on the original `va_list` in the structure) and continues working on the copied `va_list`. As far as I can tell, it is permissible. In any case, a certain amount of blocking of the original thread is required.

Comment: @IanAbbott The man page for `va_copy` states that `va_end` must be called on the destination object *in the same function*, so that won't help.

Comment: @dbush But the `va_copy` does not need to be in the same function as the `va_start`, so it could work. (1) Original thread waits for worker thread to become ready (or creates worker thread). (2) Original calls `va_start` on `va_list` inside struct for worker thread and signals worker thread (or starts worker thread). (3) Original blocks until signalled by worker. (4) Worker `va_copy`'s the `va_list` from the structure locally. (5) Worker thread signals original thread to unblock it. (6) Original calls `va_end`. (7) Worker parses copied `va_list` and calls `va_end` on it afterwards.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks man,I will  check this now!!

Comment: @IanAbbott I tried do this,basically I have a producer-consumer program.From the producer I call va_start and broadcast and at the consumer I do va_copy and parse.I face a problem at the consumer;Say at the producer the varargs are 'A','B','C',at the consumer I get 'B','C',''.What am I missing?

Comment: @adi - This sounds like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You had a problem and thought to yourself "the solution is a variadic function", which led you to a new problem... but the original problem is what you should be solving. Why do you think you will receive a long list of arguments? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: My problem is: To parse and  use the input params passed by the function in a the waiting thread .The input params already has the variable argument and is not added now.And the no of vararg param will also be long.

Comment: @adl Threads were not part of the standard C language until the C11 specification, and in C11 they are optional. So if your C compiler does not have C11 threads, its varargs implementation might not work across threads.

Comment: @IanAbbott Does it mean,I have to use c11 threads instead of normal pthreads?

Comment: @adl Not necessarily. It depends whether your compiler's varargs implementation is thread-aware. I'm not sure how common C11 thread support is. GCC/Glibc on Linux typically doesn't support C11 threads, but its varargs implementation might be thread-aware. Essentially, it boils down to whether the implementation of `va_copy` makes an actual copy of the argument list or just copies a pointer to the original argument list (which would be invalid once the function that called `va_start` returned).

Comment: My intention is to create a Logging program running in a separate thread.My waiting thread is going to be my log thread and the main thread is going to be the one which actually logs(i.e give log statements to the log thread).Could someone suggest me a good example!!

Answer (score 3):

To access variable arguments, you need to use the stdarg family of functions / macros:

```
void fun1(char* c,int i,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, i);
    // do something with args
    va_end(args);
    // args is no longer usable    
}
```

While you can pass `args` to another function, you need to be careful about using it in another thread.  Once you call `va_end` and `fun1` exits, `args` is no longer usable.  Using `va_copy` also won't work because you still need to call `va_end` on the new object *int the same function*.

If you're performing complicated operations on the arguments, you'll want to parse them first in the current thread, then make the parsed arguments available to another thread.

For example:

```
enum paramtype {
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_DOUBLE,
    TYPE_STRING
};

struct param {
    enum paramtype type;
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
        char *s;
    } data;
};

void fun1(char* c,int i,...)
{
    int x;
    va_list args;

    struct param *params = malloc(sizeof(*params) * i);

    va_start(args, i);
    for (x=0; x<i; x++) {
        params[i].type = c[i];
        switch (params[i].type) {
        case TYPE_INT:
            params[i].data.i = va_arg(args, int);
            break;
        case TYPE_DOUBLE:
            params[i].data.d = va_arg(args, double);
            break;
        case TYPE_STRING:
            params[i].data.s = strdup(va_arg(args, char *));
            break;
        }
    }
    va_end(args);

    handle_args_in_other_thread(params, i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the repl dbush..But I want to pass these things to a structure.How shall I add them?

Comment: I want these things to be done in a different thread .How do I do that?

Comment: @adi Doing so in a separate thread is not possible unless you use a mutex to make `fun1` wait until the parsing is done, at which point using a separate thread is useless.  Because a `va_list` is an opaque data structure which may use macros, you can't just copy it to another thread and expect things to work.

Comment: I already have a waiting thread which will be notified soon after I get the input arguments and I want my waiting thread to parse my input arguments.So the main thread which calls the function fun1 will not be waiting.

Comment: @adi And that is exactly the problem.  When `fun1` returns and calls `va_end`, `args` goes out of scope so you can't use it in another thread.  What exactly are you doing as part of the parsing that you think warrants it being done in another thread?  There's a good chance you don't need to.

Comment: Will I be able to use all these three lines in my other thread?My arguments will be very lengthy and I write them to a file also and I dont want them to be parsed in the same calling thread .

Comment: @adi  The parsing should take a trivial amount of time regardless of the amount of parameters.  Do that in the current thread, then take the parsed arguments and make them accessible to the other thread where you write to disk.

Comment: @adi, if the reason you're looking at varargs is the length of your argument list, then you are looking in the wrong place.  Organize the data you want to pass into appropriate data structures *first*, and pass those.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write or find a third-party implementation of a map structure similar to `std::map` from C++. You cannot define a `struct` with dynamic members because they must all be known at compile-time.

Comment: Why would he? the data is on the stack, available through the `va_list` structure... there's no need to move the data to the heap.

Comment: @Myst It depends on the desired lifetime of the `va_list`. It's contents are only valid between the `va_start` and `va_end` calls, so if it is desired to save something that persists after the `va_end` call, `va_list` is not suitable for that purpose.

Comment: True. At the same time, there’s no way of placing the data in any type of data structure before it’s parsed for type data... which means that your answer reflects one way to implement the post-parsing stage. With all due respect, your answer doesn’t seem to answer the question (how to forward the unparsed data to a different function).

Comment: @Myst My reading of the question is how to parse the data into a data structure then forward **that** to another function.

Comment: @Myst I want to pass the unparsed data and notify a waiting thread and let that thread parse my data..

Comment: IMHO, you probably misread. It says the parsing is performed by the other function. In the comments, OP clarified that they wish the parsing to be performed in a separate thread... (which adds limitations that maker doubt if this is the best approach).

Comment: @Myst Yup, I agree that I seem to have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I really hate that I down voted the answer... I think it was my aversion to C++ references as much as the thought that the answer was missing the question. If you feel like updating the answer to it addresses the question, I'd be happy to reverse my vote.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a c function which accepts variable arguments. **I want to store
>   all the arguments of this function(along with the vararg) in a
>   structure** and pass that structure to another function which will parse
>   all the elements in the structure. But I dont know how to add the
>   variable argument obtained to the structure.

C has a data type, `va_list`, for holding and extracting data from a set of variable arguments.  For a variadic function to do *anything* with with its variable arguments, it must use this type and the associated macros for manipulating it.  For example,

```
void fun1(char* c, int i, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, i);
    // can now access the variable arguments via 'args' ...
```

It is explicitly permitted to pass a `va_list` to another function for it to operate upon, and there is no particular reason why it could not be put in a structure (as it is a *complete* object type):

```
struct args {
    char *c;
    int i;
    va_list ap;
};

// ...

    struct args args;
    va_start((args.ap), i);
```

(Parentheses placed around `args.ap` out of an abundance of caution).

You can then pass either that structure or a pointer to it to another function to process:

```
    process_arguments(args);
```

or

```
    process_pointer_to_arguments(&args);
```

HOWEVER, although in this and other ways you can expose one function's variable argument list to another, and that other can process it, you should not assume it safe to to continue to use a given `va_list` for any purpose after the varargs function with which it is associated returns, even though such an object itself can have a longer lifetime.

In any case, do not forget that the function that initializes a `va_list`, whether via `va_start` as shown above or via the `va_copy` macro that can also serve that purpose, is responsible also for using the `va_end` macro to clean up.  That your functions correctly and reliably do this would be another reason not to use a `va_list` after the call on which it is based returns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I have one doubt.Basically the reason I want to add vararg to a structure is to notify another thread and use that thread to parse the varargs and process it further.You mentioned that the function is responsible  to do va_end also.But I dont want my main thread to wait.How do I do the vastart,vaend also in my another thread?

Comment: @adi without va_start you cannot get va_list, and you must do va_start and va_end in the same function, so what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: @adi, you cannot do this.  The need for `va_end` is a detail.  The main point here is that once the varargs function returns, it is not safe to continue using its `va_list`, *even if you don't clean it up via `va_end`*.